# Programmatically added DataGridViewRow gets lost

Tags: c#, datagridview

As described in the topic, I'm trying to add a new Row to my Datagridview.
In the Constructor of the form I'm setting AllowUserToAddRows to false.
I'm still able to add the row programmatically but it doesn't seem to get saved in my Settings File.

Here's the code of my form - I left some (hopefully not essential) parts out:
P.S.: pay attention to my comment at the end of my btnAddEntry_Click()-Method

```
public DataSettings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Import rows that are saved int settings
        for (int i = 0; i < Properties.Settings.Default.colNames.Count; i++)
        {
            dgv.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
            dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = Properties.Settings.Default.colNames[i];
            dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = Properties.Settings.Default.colStarts[i];
            dgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = Properties.Settings.Default.colWidths[i];
        }

        //Hide "new row"-row
        dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    }

    private void cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }

    private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.colNames = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
        Properties.Settings.Default.colStarts = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
        Properties.Settings.Default.colWidths = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Index < dgv.Rows.Count - 1)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.colNames.Add((String)row.Cells[0].Value);
                Properties.Settings.Default.colStarts.Add((String)row.Cells[1].Value);
                Properties.Settings.Default.colWidths.Add((String)row.Cells[2].Value);
            }
        }
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }

    private void btnAddEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
        Dialogs.Data_AddRow newRow = new Dialogs.Data_AddRow();
        newRow.ShowDialog();
        dgv.Rows.Add(new string[] { newRow.parmName, newRow.parmStart, newRow.parmWidth });
        newRow.Dispose();
        dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = false;  //If I comment out this line - It works fine.
                                         //but then the "newrow"-row is visible
    }

    private void btnDeleteEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgv.Rows.Remove(dgv.SelectedRows[0]);
    }

    private void btnDeleteAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgv.Rows.Clear();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are losing info of last row because of this line: `(row.Index < dgv.Rows.Count - 1)` should be `(row.Index < dgv.Rows.Count)` or just get rid of it.

If you want to check if the last row is not `NewRow` when saving do this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
{
    if (!row.IsNewRow)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.colNames.Add((String)row.Cells[0].Value);
        Properties.Settings.Default.colStarts.Add((String)row.Cells[1].Value);
        Properties.Settings.Default.colWidths.Add((String)row.Cells[2].Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my god :D - thx a bunch! Of course! If only I had commented the "-1" xD